# Find $\Theta$ of a "mystery" function

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I have the following function

[image]
I was able to find the worst-case run time of this as $O(n^3)$

How do I find the lower bound $\Omega$ of it though? This is what I have

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1\\$

$= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n}j\\$

$= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{i(i-1)}{2})\\$

$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n^2+n-i^2+i)\\$

$= \frac{1}{2}((n-1)n^2 + (n-1)n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i)\\$

$= \frac{1}{2}(n^3 - n - \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2})\\$

$= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{6n^3 - 6n}{6} - \frac{2n^3 - n^2 - 2n^2 + n}{6} + \frac{3n^2-3n}{6})\\$

$= \frac{1}{12}(6n^3 - 6n - (2n^3 - 3n^2 + n) + (3n^2-3n))$

$= \frac{1}{12}(6n^3 - 6n - 2n^3 + 3n^2 - n + 3n^2-3n)$

$= \frac{(4n^3 + 6n^2 - 10n)}{12}$

$= \frac{(2n^3 + 3n^2 - 5n)}{6}$